# Testing `instanceof` is redundant and can be replaced with `!= null`?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

In AndroidStudio, which uses intellij, i am getting the following suggestion in my code. I was wondering why this suggestion is being made.

I have multiple `Child` classes that inherit from `ParentB` and `ParentB` inherits from `ParentA`.

I have a condition that needs to test which child class i have of `ParentB`. Let's say that i have 4 children. `ChildA`, `ChildB`, `ChildC` and `ChildD`. All these children inherit from `Child`.

So i have the following:

```
public void test(Child myChild) {

    anotherTest((ChildA)myChild);
    if (myChild instanceof ChildA) {
        //dosomething
    } else if(myChild instanceof ChildB) {
        //dosomething
    }
}

public void anotherTest(ChildA theChild) {
    //dosomething
}
```

---

```
public ParentB extends ParentA {
}

public Child extends ParentB {
}

public ChildA extends Child {
}
```

When i am testing the condition i get the following suggestion. `Condition "myChild instanceof ChildA" is redundant and can be replaced with "!=null"`.

Why am i getting that suggestion? Is the suggestion accurate?

---

Edit.

I added the method before the condition. After commenting out the method it takes away the suggestion. Is it because it already tries to cast it to `ChildA` and would have failed there. So, the ide just assumes it passes there and says you can just check for null after that?

Thanks

Comment: It would really help if you'd show us a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. I suspect there's more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: The example is still not _complete_, e.g. `ChildB` is missing or what you are doing in the if-blocks.

Comment: Just a guess here because we're lacking information: if you're checking _all_ subclasses of `Child` and always do the same inside the blocks the IDE might figure that the _only way_ not to "doSomething" would be if `myChild` was null.

Comment: Added more details and something i found when commenting out some sections.

Comment: Still not enough, please have a look here and follow the instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How hard is it to extract the problem from your code. It should have been done before you even consider posting on SO, all you're resulting in now is people guessing at whatever mistake you could have made.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the first place. You should be calling a method defined in the base class which is overridden by each derived class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If myChild is not an instance of ChildA (and not null) you will get a ClassCastException when calling anotherTest().

So your if block is only reachable when myChild is null or an instance of ChildA and your instanceof check is redundant.

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was assuming was happening from the comments i made in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

The case:

```
if(obj instanceof MyClass) {...}
```

and

```
if (obj == null) {...}
```

return false in both cases if the object is not null.  This is because a null reference is not an instance of anything.  That makes sense.  But `instanceof` is not redundant at all. It is the other way around.  Checking explicitly for null is redundant if you need to check if particular object is an instance of some class.  For example:

```
if(obj == null) {...} // This check is redundant
else if (obj instanceof MyClass) {...}
```

Therefore, the suggestion "***Condition "myChild instanceof ChildA" is redundant and can be replaced with "!=null"***" is not accurate at all.

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
Orange orange = new Orange();
```

Neither of these objects are null, nor they are compatible (`instanceof`) with each other.

```
if (apple instanceof Orange) {...} // false
if (orange instanceof Apple) {...} // false
if (apple != null) {...} // true: does this mean an apple 'is-an' orange?
if (orange != null) {...} // true: does this mean an orange 'is-an' apple?
```

***Conclusion***: Checking object references using `instanceof` is not redundant because it includes the check for null.